# ZF2: inject variables in constructor of service

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2, service-locator

Is there a way to create a new instance of a service and adding constructor parameters? I am a bit new to depency injection, and I find I can only add services as constructor parameters and not runtime variables through a factory.

The code I have looks similar to this:

```
Class MyService
{
    private $name;
    private $active;

    public function __construct($name,$active)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->active = $active;    
    }
}

$myService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyService')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way by using the `MutableCreationOptionsTrait` trait in your factory.

```
class YourServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    use MutableCreationOptionsTrait;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (isset($this->creationOptions['name'])) {
            // do something with the name option
        }

        if (isset($this->creationOptions['active'])) {
            // do something with the active option
        }

        $yourService = new YourService(
            $this->creationOptions['active'], 
            $this->creationOptions['name']
        );

        return $yourService;
    }
}
```

The above shown code implements the trait for creation options. With this trait you can handle an array of options in your factory. Call your service like in the following code.

```
$yourService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(YourService::class, [
    'active' => true,
    'name' => 'Marcel',
]);
```

Easy as pie. ;)

Comment: Hi Marcel, thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I googled the mutableCreationOptionsInterface and found this post: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/issues/7. Apparently it is only available in the plugin manager. In ZF3 however it is available in the service manager.

Comment: Which version of ZF2 are you using exactly?

Comment: I'm currently using version: 2.2.6

Comment: As far as I  can see the `MutableCreationOptionsInterface` is already present in 2.2.6 with callables. I would test it anyway. If this way does not work, try using the plugin solution as described in your link. Beside that, I strongly recommend to update to the latest 2.x version of zend framework, where `MutableCreationOptions` work pretty fine.

Comment: I just updated to the latest stable ZF2 version. Still not working. I think I'll just go for setter methods, and plan a migration to ZF3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your service exists:

```
Class MyService
{
    private $name;
    private $active;

    public function __construct($name,$active)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->active = $active;    
    }
}
```

If instead of `->get()`'ing it, you could `->build()` it :)

```
class SomeFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return $container->build(MyService::class, ['name' => "Foo", 'active' => true]);
        // Line below works as well, using a variable requested name, handy for an AbstractFactory of some kind (e.g. one that creates different adapters in the same way with same params)            
        // return $container->build($requestedName, ['name' => "Foo", 'active' => true]); 
    }
}
```

Check out the [ServiceManager `build()` function](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/0aea76faf40350852fd6570cb4c1eb60a18ac872/src/ServiceManager.php#L223)

---

Note: Not sure since when it's present, this works in higher versions of ZF2 and all of ZF3.

---

Note 2: Both `get()` and `build()` call [function `doCreate()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/0aea76faf40350852fd6570cb4c1eb60a18ac872/src/ServiceManager.php#L758). Function declaration:

> `private function doCreate($resolvedName, array $options = null)`

`get()` does: `$object = $this->doCreate($name);`

`build()` does: `return $this->doCreate($name, $options);`

Comment: Looks like this was only introduces in ZF3. I'm currently using zend-servicemanager 2.7.11 (the latest before jumping to ZF3), and I only have 2 methods: get() & has().